# How to make href work with the function result in ng-click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How do you pass the `ng-click` function result into `href` tag ? For example if i have

```
<a href = "{{value}}" target = "_blank" ng-click="myFunction()">Click Here</a>
```

where `myFunction()` returns a unique link from my server everytime I click it and I want it to be passed into the `href` tag as `value` and then open this link in a new tab without any popups.

I'm not sure how to make `href` work with the function in `ng-click` in the same tag at the same time. I've tried `$window.open()` which generates popups so I'm looking for an alternative solution.

I noticed that using `href` and `target="_blank"` opens links in a new tab without causing popups but I need a way for `href` to use the return value of `myFunction()` inside the `ng-click`.

Comment: Did you try `window.location.href = <value>;`?

Comment: Yes but that doesn't open the link in a new tab

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, it will open in a new tab

```
controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.myFunction = function(link){
            $window.open(link, '_blank');
        };
    }
]);
```

You can directly bind the url like this

```
<a ng-href="{{myFunction()}}" target="_blank" >Click Here</a>
```

Comment: yes, I used this but it causes popups. I'd like to just use href and target="_blank" to avoid popups but I need a way for href to use myFunction()'s return value when it's clicked

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<a ng-href="{{myFunction()}}" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

It will call the method and open the URL in a new window

Comment: how does the value of myFunction() get passed into thisurl?

Comment: sorry, updated the answer. The value returned from myFunction is set to href with the ng-href directive

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

**Html :**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<a ng-click="openLink('http://www.example.com')">Open Link in a new Tab</a>
</div>
```

**JS :**

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.openLink = function(link) {
            $window.open(link, '_blank');
        };
    }
]);
```

Here, `$window.open` will work same as `href` will do with target blank.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/vn0dpst0/

Answer (score 0):

Call your function using `ng-click` to open the link in new tab using `$window`. Check out **[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/8bt399xc/5/)**.

**Controller:**

```
// App declaration
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
// App controller
MyApp.controller("TestController", ["$scope", "$window", function($scope, $window) {
    var sampleLinks = [
    "http://www.google.com",
    "http://www.facebook.com",
    "http://www.twitter.com",
    "http://www.instagram.com",
    "http://www.gmail.com"
  ]
  $scope.myFunction = function() {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*sampleLinks.length);
    $window.open(sampleLinks[randomIndex], '_blank');
  };
}]);
```

**Template:**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="TestController">
  <a href="" ng-click="myFunction();">Click here</a> to open random link in a new tab!
</div>
```